# drop shadow effect on QPushButton text

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qstyle

How do I set a drop-shadow effect on a QPushButton text?

I could set shadow on the entire QPushButton using QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, I however, am not able to find a way to directly set the effect of text inside the QButton.

Edit:

I tried the following, not sure if the syntax is correct

in the .qss file:

```
MyButton::text
{
    shadow: palette(dark);
}
```

I set the button's drop shadow effect by:

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect( );
    effect->setBlurRadius( 5 );
    mStartButton->setGraphicsEffect( effect );
```

Comment: adding some code will be helpful to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Set a QLabel iside QPushButton rather than simple text. Then apply shadow effect to the label.

You may need to add extra code for centering the label inside the pushbutton.

```
mStartButton->setText("");
QLabel *label = new QLabel(mStartButton);
label->setText("<b>Button</b>");
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect( );
effect->setBlurRadius( 5 );
label ->setGraphicsEffect( effect );
```